# Find start and end in order in an array of objects - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

everyone.
Hope you are doing well.
I currently have this problem.

This is my 'Travel' Schema.

```
    const TravelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        ...
        route: [{
            index: { type: Number},
            lat: { type: Number },
            lng: { type: Number },
        }],
        ...
    });
```

This is where I handled post request.
(Save new Travel)

```
    ...
    const {route, ...rest} = req.body;
    const newTravel = new Travel({
        route: route.map((location, index) => ({index, ...location})),
        ...rest
    });
    const Travel = await newTravel.save();
    ...
```

Search by start and end locations in order.
tart and end locations are objects with 'lat' and 'lng' properties.

```
    ...
    const { start, end } = req.body;
    //start -> {lat: 51.11213, lng: 19.1239219} //for example
    const travels = await Travel.find({
        route: { $all: [ {$elemMatch: {...start}}, {$elemMatch: {...end}} ] },
        $expr: {
            $lt: [
                {$arrayElemAt: ['$route.index', {$indexOfArray: ['$route', {...start}]}]},
                {$arrayElemAt: [{$reverseArray: '$route.index'}, {$indexOfArray: [{$reverseArray: '$route'}, {...end}]}]},
            ]
        }
    });
    console.log(travels); // [] is printed
    ...
```

Without $expr, I can get some results but not accurate ones.
What I want exactly is like this:

```
    route: [{index: 0, lat: 54, lng: 13},  //same as end but not considered regarding order
            {index: 1, lat: 32, lng: 51},
            {index: 1, lat: 10, lng: 30},  //start
            {index: 2, lat: 54, lng: 13}]  //end
    start: {lat: 10, lng: 30}, end: {lat: 54, lng: 13}
    the route is filtered

    route: [{index: 0, lat: 54, lng: 13},  //end
            {index: 1, lat: 32, lng: 51},
            {index: 1, lat: 10, lng: 30}]  //start
    start: {lat: 10, lng: 30}, end: {lat: 54, lng: 13}
    the route is not filtered this time
```

Would you please help me to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello everyone. (mistyped)

Comment: The logic is not clear to me. Your DB contains documents which each contains route array. You are given input with start and end locations and you want to find all routes where the input-start-point is before the input-end-point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `$min` and `$max` with `$reduce`.
Since `$indexOfArray` returns the index of the **first** occurrence, it should not be used here, as you may have the same corrdinated multiple times. Using `$reduce` can create an array of all relevant indices for the start point and for the end point. Using `$min` and `$max` allows to check if there is a start point index that is smaller than an end-point index:

```
db.collection.find({
  route: {$all: [ {$elemMatch: {...start}}, {$elemMatch: {...end}} ] },
  $expr: {$lt: [
      {$min: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$route",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $cond: [
                {$and: [{$eq: ["$$this.lat", start.lat]}, {$eq: ["$$this.lng", start.lng]}]},
                {$concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this.index"]]},
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
      }},
      {$max: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$route",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $cond: [
                {$and: [{$eq: ["$$this.lat", end.lat]}, {$eq: ["$$this.lng", end.lng]}]},
                {$concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this.index"]]},
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
      }}
    ]
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uhQA_1SP0D4)